# Why was Protractor chosen over angular-scenario?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-scenario

What is the added value of Protractor over angular-scenario ? I tried to find out why was angular-scenario on the deprecation path, I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458949/protractor-for-testing-angularjs/19505584#19505584), and watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvAeabvZ61o)
, but I am still unsatisfied by the fact there are no obvious advantage to use Protractor.

Comment: AFAIR, running the app in an iframe was too limiting, and using JS in the browser didn't allow testing everything (like mouse gestures, and things like that).

Comment: @JBNizet with some more details, your comment could be an anwer

Comment: gontard, I agree. The comment is and should be a possible and relevant answer

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby On Rails land, capybara is one of the major integration test tools, Watir is another.  Both utilize the WebDriver api to interact with the browsers.  This is the standard way to interact with the browser/webpage for E2E testing.

Karma/ngScenarioE2E utilizes an iframe and interacts with browsers with karma plugins. While effective, its far from standard.

**This to me in the main benefit of using protractor, the low-level access to the browser.  Whether or not that's enough reason for them to switch, is really up to the google team, and it seems like they've made up their mind on this.**